# How do I add a small number into my html?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a difficult time doing this probably because I'm not sure what to even call it. But a client wants me to put a small number one in some text at the end of a sentence - wich indicates that they should find the small 1 at the bottom of the page to read more details about that particular sentence. You see this type of thing a lot on container and supplement labels. Can this be accomplished with html? Please let me know if you need clarification.

Kind of like this except instead of an astrick, a small one:

*These statements have not been evaluated by the Food and Drug Administration.  This product is not intended to diagnose, treat, cure or prevent any disease.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must be looking for superscript.

```
<p>This is <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>

<p>This is <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p>
```

## In practice:

This is <sub>subscript</sub> text.

This is <sup>superscript</sup> text.

Comment: Is this the way to go with chemical formulars like H2O?

Answer (score 2):

Use the character “¹” U+00B9 SUPERSCRIPT ONE. If you do not know how to enter it in your authoring environment (in Windows, you can usually enter it by Alt 0185), you can use the entity reference `&sup1;`.

Unlike `<sup>1</sup>` (which is what most people would use), this means using a character designed by a typographer to fit the font. The stroke width is correct, and so is the vertical placement. Using `sup` tends to mess up spacing between lines, among other things.

However, footnote references don’t work that well in HTML documents. Especially if you want to make the reference a link to the footnote itself, a tiny little superscript is very poor usability and accessibility. An expression like “[1]” is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this problem has to do with citation-referencing a resource. You can do the following:

- At the end of a sentence you can write the number of the reference(references are located         at the bottom of a webpage most of the times) like this-actually is a HTML anchor tag:

  ```
  The sentence goes here.<a href="#1"><sub>1</sub></a>
  ```
- Then at the bottom of the screen you can write the reference like this:

  ```
  <a name="1">The reference details go here.</a>
  ```